# overload delete[] operator to allow shrinkable arrays of types with destructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, realloc, delete-operator

We're trying to overload the **delete[]** operator to achieve [shrinkable oriented to objects arrays](http://ncomputers.org/content/code.php?src=suggestions/shrink%20arrays%20cpp).

It works fine with data types without specific destructor.

When the data type has a specified destructor, the **new[]** operator needs extra bytes.

Could you help us please to answer these questions?

1. Why does the **new[]** operator require extra bytes for data types with specific destructor?
2. Will always the **new[]** operator request these bytes or is it library dependent?
3. Is it possible to know if the data type has a specific destructor with an **if statement**?

The code should throw an unhandled exception when it tries to shrink the array of B's.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void*operator new[](size_t s){
    cout<<"Block size: "<<s<<endl;
    return malloc(s);
}
void operator delete[](void*p){
    free(p);
}
void operator delete[](void*p,size_t s){
    //Is it possible to know if the data type has a specific destructor?
    bool destructor=0;
    if(destructor){
        p=(char*)p-8,s+=8;
    }
    cout<<"New block size: "<<s<<endl;
    if(realloc(p,s)!=p)throw 0;
}

struct A{
    char a;

    A():a(0){}
    ~A()=default;
};

struct B{
    char b;

    B():b(0){}
    ~B(){}
};

int main(){
    unsigned S=10,s=4;
    cout<<"Creating "<<S<<" A's"<<endl;
    A*a=new A[S];
    cout<<"Creating "<<S<<" B's"<<endl;
    B*b=new B[S];
    cout<<"Shrinking A to "<<s<<" elements"<<endl;
    operator delete[](a,sizeof(A)*s);
    cout<<"Shrinking B to "<<s<<" elements"<<endl;
    operator delete[](b,sizeof(B)*s);
    cout<<"Deleting A and B"<<endl;
    delete[]b,delete[]a;
    return 0;
}
```

Related answered question:

[overload delete[] operator with specific arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078560/overload-delete-operator-with-specific-arguments)

Comment: I think any extra space needed by new operators is implementation defined and relying on it is a bad idea. Why do you use , operator instead of {} for your if statement? That's not the common practice.

Comment: "operator instead of {} for your if statement" I don't understand you :(

Comment: `if(destructor)p=(char*)p-8,s+=8;` is more conventionally written as `if(destructor) { p=(char*)p-8; s+=8; }`

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the code you posted? http://ideone.com/9KkWFE

Comment: Maybe this helps if you can use C++11?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible

Comment: Neil Kirk, it is one habit I have. Thank you for the observation. The expected result is exactly the same, but with: "Block size: 18" insted of "Block size: 14"

Comment: Just to be clear, the program run I linked aborts with error. Do you expect the code to run without error?

Comment: Neil Kirk: Yes, it throws an exception when "shrinks" the "b" array, because the pointer is eight or four bytes greater than, the address where the block starts.

Comment: `reall9c` is illegal if the data stored has a destructor: you are copyimg bits without copying the object, which should only work for a restricted set of types.

Comment: Yakk: The purpose of the call to realloc is to shrink the array, when the code moves the array copying its elements, an exception is thrown:     if(realloc(p,s)!=p)throw 0;

Comment: I see. You are only permitting calls that will decrease size of the block. To reply to someone, use @Yakk so they will be notified.

Comment: @ncomp naturally moving can occur even when shrinking.  Note that thr magnitude of the error is so large that an exception is insufficient: terminate.  Exception means the program is in a valid state, while you just exeduted undefined behavior.

Comment: @ncomputers.org `if(realloc(p,s)!=p)` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @Yakk we've made a four hours test to know if the realloc function can move the data when shrinking the array to random sizes. With GNU compiler and glibc, reallocation did never happen. With other compilers maybee it is possible. "Note that thr magnitude of the error is so large that an exception is insufficient: terminate." I didn't understand you :(

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't understand you... In which compiler?

Comment: @NeilKirk With this link  ideone.com/9KkWFE you've proven that the amount of bytes, that the new[] operator requests for types with specific destructor may vary. Why don't you try to post an answer for the question nr. 2?

Comment: @nocom throwimg an exception is for a recoverable error.  If memory for a non-trivially copyable class is moved without warning, that is a non-recoverable error.  You should terminate the program, not throw, in that case.  Also note you may need to figure out what happens to the objects: your delete should destroy first, now that I think about it, so maybe realloc does not matter.  But then it means you need to reconstruct.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you very much for your answer. So far I know, an unhandled exception usually terminates the program. Which other mode to terminate a program can you teach me? "Also note you may need to figure out what happens to the objects: your delete should destroy first, now that I think about it, so maybe realloc does not matter. But then it means you need to reconstruct" What do you think about this suggestion? http://ncomputers.org/content/code.php?src=suggestions/shrink%20arrays%20cpp

Comment: @ncomputers.org in standard C++. Another problem is that it'll behave differently depending on whether `p` is checked before or after the realloc call (`!=` doesn't have left-right evaluation)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you very much for your answer. I think that I understand you. 'realloc(p,s)' doesn't assign a new value for 'p', it only returns the new address of the block. Are you talking about 'if(p!=p)'? How do you insert characters as code in comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may answer points **1** and **2**

> When operator `new` is used to create a new array, a cookie is usually
>   stored to remember the allocated length (number of array elements) so
>   that it can be deallocated correctly.
>
> Specifically:
>
> ```
> No cookie is required if the array element `type T` has a trivial destructor.
> ```

That means:

- Because struct A has a trivial destructor it doesn't require a
  cookie.
- Because struct B has a specific destructor it requires a cookie of `sizeof(size_t)` bytes, which is stored inmediatly at the left of the array.

Reference: [Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#array-cookies)